# MAMP : Apache not starting while httpd is already running

Tags: php, macos, apache, mamp

I have strange problem here. I was installing mcrypt on my mac running yosemite and MAMP 3.0, PHP 5.6.1

Extension seemed like installed successfully. But when I restarted mac, MAMP was unable to start Apache, while mysql was running very fine.

I came to know that port 80 in blocked. httpd is already using it. I tried restarting several times but it is already in use. I have very little idea about apache using httpd to run server.

I can run apache on different port (8080, here) but I don't want to run it entering :8080 each time while testing on localhost.

Any help really appreciated,

Comment: Run `lsof -i TCP:80` command to see what is using 80 port.

Comment: @umka It is the installed apache that OSX respawns automatically on boot and any time after when it dies. See answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because OSX automagically starts its own installed version of apache. The only way i found of getting rid of it is this : after boot, in a Shell,

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist
```

edit : the unload command above permanently prevents the daemon from re-spawning. After a reboot, if you

```
DarkMax:~ yvesleborg$ sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist
Password:******
```

you should get :

```
/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist: Could not find specified service
```

you should avoid at all cost changing the content of the `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons` folder outside of the `launchctl` command.

Comment: yes thats working! My MAMP was running fine until I installed mcrypt with brew. Don't know where I touched apache.

Comment: Is there no way to delete this entry? I’ve been trying to delete /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist but OS X doesn’t allow me to. I even tried booting in single user mode and it still gave me error that it’s a system file and I cannot rm, chmod or chown it. I tried the same as root by enabling it from directory services and still got same result.

Comment: @SaifurRahmanMohsin : that command should be definitive. I edited my answer to show the 'after reboot' state.

Comment: Oh that is good news. I have not restarted my system yet so I haven’t noticed the command’s definitive effect. Thanks a lot!

Comment: That's exactly what I did, and really it simply worked, I don't know how I got to a state where I needed to do that.